# While loop makes applet white screen and unresponsive

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Here is my loop code (This is the only code relating to my loop):

```
while(true)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            System.out.println("1");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

When I launch the applet, it white screens and I cannot close it unless I press the "Terminate" button in eclipse.

Comment: You have infinite loop. What did you think was going to happen other than a complete freeze?

Comment: while(true){} is a loop forever and there is no break; So why or what should stop the loop except of a thrown exception?

Answer (score 3):

You're blocking the UI Thread with an infinite `while` loop. You don't say whether you're using an AWT or Swing applet, either way the result will be the same. If you're using a Swing applet, use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). If you're using the old heavyweight AWT, convert it to Swing and follow the previous advice.

Answer (score 0):

As said you made an infinity loop with:

```
while(true){
//something
}
```

There is no break; So why or what should stop the loop except of a thrown exception?

To see when a InterruptedException is thrown you should read the JavaDoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html

Answer (score 0):

You are hogging the applets EDT. You need to run your loop in another thread. Try adding `Thread gameThread;` as a variable and use
`gameThread = new Thread() {

    public void run() {

        while (condition) {

            //code here

        }

    }

}`
and then `gameThread.start()` both in your applet start method and `gameThread.join()` in your applet stop method.