# While loops seems to break painting code

Tags: java

The following code sample has been causing me some grief in a project I'm doing:

Here's my problem...

This code results in a grid of squares being drawn on the window, along with a coloured shape, starting at the top of this grid:

```
            MainWindow mainAppWindow = mainAppWindow = new MainWindow("TETRIS");
            mainAppWindow.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            mainAppWindow.setVisible(true);

            TetriminoFactory blockBuilder = mainAppWindow.getGameBoard().getBlockFactory();
            mainAppWindow.getGameBoard().setActiveTetrimino(blockBuilder.createTetrimino());
            Tetrimino activeTetrimino = mainAppWindow.getGameBoard().getActiveTetrimino();
```

After this, I have a while loop which should move the shape down the screen by a specified distance every second. This movement should be represented on the window:

```
while((activeTetrimino.getLowermostPiece().getLoc().getYPos() / MiscConsts.TETRIS_UNIT) <= mainAppWindow.getGameBoard().getLowermostRowIndex())
        {
            if(activeTetrimino.checkForNeighbouringBlock().equals(Collision.BLOCK_BELOW_ME))
            {
                if(!activeTetrimino.setSecuredState(true))
                {
                    activeTetrimino = blockBuilder.createTetrimino();
                }
            }
                activeTetrimino.moveTetrimino(0, MiscConsts.TETRIS_UNIT);
                mainAppWindow.canvas.repaint();

            try {
        Thread.sleep(MiscConsts.TIME_BETWEEN_ADVANCEMENTS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR - InterruptedException thrown in operate(). Terminating.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1000);
            }
        }
```

It's at this point I encounter an issue. The loop seems to undo all previous drawing, and a blank screen results. If I comment the loop out, the grid is drawn, along with the shape, but of course, no movement takes place. I'm not sure what's going on here, but I've a hunch it's to do with threads or something. Or perhaps just while loops are the anti-swing :P

COMPLETE EXCERPT:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            theApp = new Tetris();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                                        {
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                theApp.createGUI();     // Call GUI creator
                                            }
                                        });
    }

    public void createGUI()
    {
        MainWindow mainAppWindow = mainAppWindow = new MainWindow("TETRIS");
        mainAppWindow.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        mainAppWindow.setVisible(true);

        TetriminoFactory blockBuilder = mainAppWindow.getGameBoard().getBlockFactory();
        // NEEDS WORK???
        mainAppWindow.getGameBoard().setActiveTetrimino(blockBuilder.createTetrimino());

        Tetrimino activeTetrimino = mainAppWindow.getGameBoard().getActiveTetrimino();


        while((activeTetrimino.getLowermostPiece().getLoc().getYPos() / MiscConsts.TETRIS_UNIT) <= mainAppWindow.getGameBoard().getLowermostRowIndex())
    {
        if(activeTetrimino.checkForNeighbouringBlock().equals(Collision.BLOCK_BELOW_ME))
        {
            if(!activeTetrimino.setSecuredState(true))
            {
                activeTetrimino = blockBuilder.createTetrimino();
            }
        }
            activeTetrimino.moveTetrimino(0, MiscConsts.TETRIS_UNIT);
            mainAppWindow.canvas.repaint();

        try {
    Thread.sleep(MiscConsts.TIME_BETWEEN_ADVANCEMENTS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR - InterruptedException thrown in operate(). Terminating.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1000);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [While loop makes applet white screen and unresponsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369264/while-loop-makes-applet-white-screen-and-unresponsive) among numerous others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are calling `Thread.sleep` on the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT for short.

The EDT is where swing does all of its work.  If you put it to sleep then Swing won't do any painting or handle any user input.

One solution would be to take the body of your while loop and put it into a [SwingTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) that will run every second.

Another, much more complicated, solution would be to use an awt canvas that has its own draw context and can be drawn to in a different thread and run your loop in that thread.  Take a look at **Gamedev's** article on [Active Rendering in Java](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-active-rendering-r2418) if you'd like to take the canvas approach.

Comment: I find active rendering less complicated once you learn the boilerplate necessary to get the canvas running. It is a pity people dive right into the swing-mind when they start to learn java for gameprogramming.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you.  Once you get active rendering down it does make game dev much simpler in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to execute you loop within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The EDT is responsible for, amongst other things, processing repaint requests.  This means if you do anything that blocks this thread from running, it can't repaint the screen until what ever was blocking it has finished.

This would explain part of your problem.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Probably the simplest solution would be to replace your `while` look with `javax.swing.Timer` instead

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestBrick {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBrick();
    }

    public TestBrick() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int yPos = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    yPos++;
                    if (yPos + 10 > getHeight()) {
                        yPos = 0;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            int width = getWidth();
            int xPos = (width - 10) / 2;
            g.drawRect(xPos, yPos, 10, 10);
        }    
    }        
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the replies guys, I'll try your suggestions :)